# How to process nth elment in jQuery each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I am processing a series of elements in an `each` loop as

```
function test(){
  $('#first li').each(function(n){$(this).//here is the jQuery effects for nth li
  \\ here I want to process nth li of id="second" too
});
```

How can I simoltanously process the nth element of another id too?

For example, I want to make jQuery effects for the first `li`s of DIV `first` and `second`; then the second `li`s of both DIVs.

```
<div id="first">
  <ul>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="second">
  <ul>
    <li>to be effect with 1st li of FIRST</li>
    <li>to be effect with 2nd li of FIRST</li>
    <li>to be effect with 3rd li of FIRST</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $first =$('#first li');

var $second = $('#second li');

$second.each(function(n){
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $first.eq(n).fadeOut();
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HdkJ5/1)

---

Note:

```
<div id="first>
<div id="second>
```

Should be:

```
<div id="first">
<div id="second">

"first => "first"
"second => "second"
```

Answer (score 1):

.each() provides index as the first argument. it is zero based index.
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: I believe he knows that already, you can see in his question he's using the `index` parameter, he's calling it `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(){
  $('#first li').each(function(index, element){
      $(this).bar(); // or $(element).bar();
      $('#second li').eq(index).doSomething();
  });
}
```

`<div id="first> and <div id="second>` should `<div id="first"> and <div id="second">`